# OAuth2 POST Data : Error 403 Forbidden for URL

Tags: django, oauth-2.0

I'm using `OAuth2` and `Django-Rest_Framework` in my applications.

When i try `GET` and in my applications it works.But i got an error as mentioned when i try to `POST` it.

I try both method in Postman and it works well..

Did i missing something in O`Auth2 settings`?

This is my code to `POST` using `Angular2`

```
PostLevelling(test: Test) {
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/test/', {headers: this.getHeaders()})
    .map((res:Response) => res.json());
  }
```

Comment: How is this related to OAuth2? You didn't include any details about your API security, what you send in the headers, your `test` endpoint, about what you have tried (and with what results).

Comment: `private getHeaders(){
    let headers = new Headers({
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + this.oauthService.getAccessToken()
    });
    return headers;
  }`

Comment: Your browser will send preflight OPTIONS request which doesn't have Authorization header. Therefore you need to mark OPTIONS request as save. Othervise the response will have error code and Angular won't send POST. Postman doesn't send OPTIONS while its not browser so it works. Had the same problem with django-jwt and angular.